I got a dependency conflict when I installed @nuxtjs/i18n using pnpm in nuxt project
I want to use @nuxtjs/i18n npm package in a project created with nuxt3 version. When I import modules in nuxt.config.ts after installing using pnpm, terminal error in @intlify/core-base package occurs.
steps:

pnpm install @nuxtjs/i18n@next --save-dev
The version of @nuxtjs/i18n in package.json is "9.0.0-alpha.1"

nuxt.config.ts configuration:
modules: ['@nuxt/eslint', '@element-plus/next', '@unocss/nuxt', '@pinia/nuxt', '@nuxtjs/i18n'


error image
I tried to change the @nuxtjs/i18n version but it didn't work. @intlify+shared@10.0.0-beta.5 only exists in pnpm.lock.yaml. I hope to resolve dependency conflicts allowing me to use @nuxtjs/i18n in nuxt projects
